# PC is freezing after starting laravel project

Tags: firefox, 17.10, laravel

My pc is freezing When I started a laravel project. I'm opening my browser (firefox), opening my local web site, then pc starts freezing.. How can I fix that ?

Ubuntu version: 17.10

Comment: Please add some more details. What do you mean with 'starts freezing'?

Comment: Pc slow down,  I can't even move my cursor

Comment: Can you run `top` in a terminal when this occurs and include a screenshot of it here?

Comment: I couldn't take ss, but saw that. (php 7.1 -- cpu %98 -- mem %47 )

Comment: So something in Laravel is hogging the CPU and memory. I don't know anything about Laraval, but let it execute until timeout, and check logs for errors would be a basic first step.